# Long-term symmetric key storage

Tags: encryption, key-management, secret-sharing

I have some sensitive data that I need to encrypt and retain long-term (i.e., 5+ years at least). I'd ideally like to secure it using multiple [hardware devices](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209074/what-are-the-differences-between-hsm-and-se) via a Shamir share. Something like:

```
data_key = gen_symmetric()
encrypted_data = encrypt_and_mac(key=data_key, payload=data_to_encrypt)
s1, s2, s3 = shamir(k=2, n=3, secret=data_key)
k1, k2, k3 = gen_symmetric(), gen_symmetric(), gen_symmetric()
encrypted_secrets = encrypt_and_mac(k1, s1) || encrypt_and_mac(k2, s2) || encrypt_and_mac(k3, s3)
output_to_save = encrypted_data || encrypted_secrets
```

With the idea to then save `k1`, `k2`, and `k3` in hardware. (Along with some indication of which was the first, 2nd, 3rd secret).

This feels like I'm reinventing the wheel. Is there an existing standard for doing this or a similar crypto scheme? This [related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32714/standards-for-secure-key-backup-of-master-keys-with-secret-sharing) suggests no. In that case, is the above scheme secure against an attacker that obtains one of the 3 devices?